# How to remove specific digits in dataframe columns in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes d1 and d2. My data frames are census data from 2010. I want to merge them using a common attribute

```
merge (d1, d2, by.x="GEOID", by.y= "GISJOIN")
```

d1 has the common id as GEOID (for eg. 310019654001) while d2 has the same id attribute as GISJOIN (for eg. 31000109654001). I need to remove the "0" from the 3rd and 7th position in the GISJOIN attribute. How can I do that  in R?

I splitted the values using

```
splitted <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(d2$GISJOIN, function(x) substring(x, first=c(1,4,8), last=c(2,6,14)))))

splitted$v4 <- (paste(splitted$V1, splitted$V2, splitted$V3))
```

v4 is character values, when I do as.numeric it gives me error: Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long to type as a comment, using the only example you have provided and another invented example to show you don't need the sapply() :

```
d2 = data.frame(GISJOIN=c("31000109654001","12345678910112"))
d2$GISJOIN = as.character(d2$GISJOIN)
```

What you have now:

```
splitted <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(d2$GISJOIN, function(x) substring(x, first=c(1,4,8), last=c(2,6,14)))))

splitted$v4 <- (paste(splitted$V1, splitted$V2, splitted$V3))

               V1  V2      V3             v4
31000109654001 31 001 9654001 31 001 9654001
12345678910112 12 456 8910112 12 456 8910112
```

The new string still has spaces in between, hence if you convert as.numeric() it gives NA. Below I just split it into characters and exclude position 3 and 7:

```
d2$new = lapply(strsplit(d2$GISJOIN,""),function(i){
                          paste(i[-c(3,7)],collapse="")
                           })

as.numeric(d2$new)
[1] 310019654001 124568910112
```